# integrating characteristic functions

Tags: real-analysis

let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space. suppose $E,F\in M$ are disjoint. And $\mu(E)=a^p$ and $\mu(F)=b^p$ where $a,b>0$ and $0<p<1$, then we have $\bigg(\int|1_E+1_F|^p d\mu\bigg)^\frac{1}{p}=(a^p+b^p)^\frac{1}{p}$.

This makes sense intuitively, since integral of a simple function is its measure. But can someone fill in the detail for me for the above equality? I just don't see how the author arrive at that equality, unless I can just say $\bigg(\int|1_E+1_F|^p d\mu\bigg)^\frac{1}{p}=(\mu(E)+\mu(F))^\frac{1}{p}$. I would believe this if the sum of the characteristic functions isn't raised to $p$ power. But I think I can't just do the integration like that since we raised it to some power. Can someone help me understand this?

Thanks!

Comment: $|1_E+1_F|^p=1_E+1_F$ by disjointness. Prove this equality by evaluating pointwise for $x\in X$ and considering the obvious cases.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks, this is utterly trivial now, when you point that out.